# How can I use unnest on a list-column of sf objects?

Tags: r, tidyr, r-sf

I have a tibble with a list-column composed of sf objects. Each of these sf objects has one or more polygon rows. Similar to how I would unnest a list of tibbles, I am hoping to unnest sf objects.

The data look something like this

```
library(sf)
library(tibble)
poly <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,3,3,0,0),c(0,0,3,3,0))))

a = st_sf(st_sfc(poly,poly))
b = st_sf(st_sfc(poly,poly))

df <- tibble(name=c('a','b'),poly=list(a,b))
```

I'd like the result to be an sf object that look something like this:

```
|name | geometry |
|-----|----------|
|a    | POLYGON  |
|a    | POLYGON  |
|b    | POLYGON  |
|b    | POLYGON  |
```

However, when I use unnest I receive an error, and unnest.sf can't be found for some reason.

EDIT: I'm using sf version 0.7-4

Thank you!

Ben

Comment: Do you have `tidyr` loaded in order to use `unnest`? I'm using tidyr 0.8.3, sf 0.7-6 and can unnest into something similar to what you're looking for. It's a data frame with a column `poly` of `sf` geometries; a call to `st_as_sf` then gets me a proper `sf` object

Comment: @camille I can reproduce this with tidyr 1.0.0. Maybe a regression?

Comment: I'm using tidyr 0.8.3 and upgraded to sf 0.7-7. I think it worked, but I get some warnings. If I do: st_as_sf(unnest(df)). I get an sf object that appears correct but I also get warning messages. Maybe this is fine? "Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'sfc_POLYGON' elements may not preserve their attributes
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'sfc_POLYGON' elements may not preserve their attributes"

Answer (score 1):

Following the new terminology it would be more `unchop()` than `unnest()`. Here's a way to do it :

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

poly <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,3,3,0,0),c(0,0,3,3,0))))

a = st_sf(st_sfc(poly,poly))
b = st_sf(st_sfc(poly,poly))

df <- tibble(name=c('a','b'),poly=list(a,b))

unchop_poly <- function(data, col) {
  mutate(data, {{col}} := map({{col}}, ~split(., seq_len(nrow(.))))) %>%
    unchop({{col}})
}
df2 <- df %>% 
  unchop_poly(poly)

df2
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   name  poly            
#>   <chr> <list>          
#> 1 a     <df[,1] [1 x 1]>
#> 2 a     <df[,1] [1 x 1]>
#> 3 b     <df[,1] [1 x 1]>
#> 4 b     <df[,1] [1 x 1]>

df2$poly
#> [[1]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>               st_sfc.poly..poly.
#> 1 POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 ...
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>               st_sfc.poly..poly.
#> 1 POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 ...
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>               st_sfc.poly..poly.
#> 1 POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 ...
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>               st_sfc.poly..poly.
#> 1 POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data.table` to bind the lists together by group, then convert back as an `sf` object

```
library(sf)
library(tibble)
poly <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,3,3,0,0),c(0,0,3,3,0))))
poly2 <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0))))

a = st_sf(st_sfc(poly,poly))
b = st_sf(st_sfc(poly2,poly2))

df <- tibble(name=c('a','b'),poly=list(a,b))
```

```
library(data.table)

setDT( df )[, rbindlist( poly ), by = name ] %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf()


# Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  POLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
# name             st_sfc.poly..poly.
# 1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 ...
# 2    a POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 ...
# 3    b POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 ...
# 4    b POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 ...
```